# Reading data from multiple text files (EOF, Do-Until)

Tags: vba, excel

I want my macros to read certain lines from each text files (saved in a server folder) but so far, I can only get the macros to return the correct values for from the first text file...

I think it's because I don't really understand the 'Open xxx for input as #1' command... here is the macros:

```
Public CurrCell As Range
Public noLines As Integer

Sub NextCell()

    Dim myFile As String
    noLines = InputBox("Enter the number of TRs to add")
    Range("A1").Activate

    For Each CurrCell In Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(noLines + 1, 1))
        myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = myFile
    Next CurrCell
End Sub

Sub GrabData()

    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim textline As String
    Dim Incidental As Integer
    Dim TotalAccom As Integer
    Dim Incidental_value As String
    Dim TotalAccom_value As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To noLines
        myFileName = Cells(i + 1, 1)

        Open myFileName For Input As #1            
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, textline
            text = text & textline
        Loop            
        Close #1

        Incidental = InStr(text, "INCIDENTAL ALLOWANCE")
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = Mid(text, Incidental + 22, 5)                                     
    Next i

End Sub
```

The first sub is to ask users to enter and select how many text files they want to read, and the second sub is suppose to bring back the correct values for each text file.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: There seems no relation between the two subs. Should you call `GrabData` in `Sub NextCell` before `Next CurrCell` (grab data as soon as a file is selected) or after it to grab data from those files afterwards? And the point of using `CurrCell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
Public noLines As Long ' Use Public if this is to be accessed by another Module

Sub NextCell()
    Dim i As Long, oRng As Range

    noLines = CLng(InputBox("Enter the number of TRs to add"))
    ' First store all the filenames, store them below A1
    Set oRng = Range("A1")
    For i = 1 To noLines
        oRng.Offset(i, 0).Value = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Next
    Set oRng = Nothing
    ' Then invoke the sub "GrabData"
    GrabData
End Sub

Sub GrabData()
    Const sMarker = "INCIDENTAL ALLOWANCE"
    Dim i As Long, oRng As Range
    'Dim myFileName As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim textline As String
    Dim Incidental As Long
    'Dim TotalAccom As Integer
    'Dim Incidental_value As String
    'Dim TotalAccom_value As String

    Set oRng = Range("A1")
    For i = 1 To noLines
        text = "" ' Reset the text to blank!
        ' Now go through the list of filenames stored below A1
        Open oRng.Offset(i, 0).Value For Input As #1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, textline
            text = text & textline
        Loop
        Close #1
        ' Get location of text after sMarker
        Incidental = InStr(text, sMarker) + Len(sMarker) + 2
        ' Store 5 characters of text after sMarker to column C
        oRng.Offset(i, 2).Value = Mid(text, Incidental, 5)
    Next i
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi PatricK,  Thank you SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO much for your answer, and really appreciate your comment on the steps... even I can understand what you are trying to do!!!!  You are a great teacher :)

Comment: Thanks, you can even drop the use on `Public noLines`, in GrabData, drop the `i` as well if you use `Do Until IsEmpty(oRng)...Loop` with little adjustment.

Comment: Actually, make it questions!!!  I need to retrieve "Car Hire" also from the .txt file, but unfortunately the first line that contains the word "Car Hire" is not the one I want... is it possible to read the file from EOF back to the start (as the one I want is located near the bottom of the files)?  Also another line I need to retrieve is "Excess Costs" but the format of the line is "Excess Costs" + XXXXXXX (users entered, variable in length) + $#.## (this line is located at the end of the .txt files as well).  Thanks again!

Comment: Due to uncertainty of the structure of the txt file, I would extract these informations within the `Do Until EOF(1) Loop`. If the "Excess Costs" and the number is on same line, then it's pretty easy.